# 各OSで標準インストール時にすぐに使用できるプログラミング言語について

Tags: プログラミング言語

Windows,MacOS,Linux(Ubuntu,CentOS,Debian),FreeBSD
でそれぞれのOSで標準インストール直後にすぐに使用できる(ビルトイン)プログラミング言語を教えて下さい。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: インストールしたばかりの現物環境がないと答えにくく、回答にとても労力が必要に思えます。LinuxやFreeBSDは自分でインストールして確認してみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: 一見すると「開発者視点」に見えますが、コメントを踏まえると「利用者ありき」で選定しようとしているようにも見えるのが質問を分かりにくくしているように感じます。 / また、Linux や BSD は "ディストリビューション" 毎に異なる配布形態を取っているので、一つのOSとして答えるのは難しいと思います。

Answer (score 4):

挙げられたOSに共通するプログラミング言語は存在しないでしょう。また現代ではコンピューターはプログラミング用途よりも他の用途が主流となっています。更にプログラミングを支援する様々なツールが用意されているため、インストール直後にすぐに使用できるようにはあまり考えられていません（開発者が望むツールをインストールすることが想定されています）。

その上で、一例としてWindowsについて答えます。Windows 7以降であれば以下が標準でインストールされています。

- C# コンパイラ
- Visual Basicコンパイラ
- PowerShell（廃止予定とは言えIDEも付属します）
- CMD（いわゆるバッチファイル）
- JScript実行環境
- VBScript実行環境

Comment: ご回答を受けて質問内容を編集させていただきました。共通してインストール直後に使えるプログラミング言語が知りたいとも取れる内容でした。失礼いたしました。

Comment: @池本雅也 共通でもなく特定のOSでもなく、複数のOSについて同時に尋ねる理由がわかりませんでした。同時に尋ねる裏の理由があり、そこに信に求めたい質問が隠れていたりしませんか？ [XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2702/4236)も参照。

Comment: 網羅的にデータとして把握しておきたかったというのが理由です。標準装備のコンパイラを対象にバイナリを作成すればユーザ側が余計なプログラムを準備する（ユーザに準備させる）手間などを回避できるかもと思ったからです。

Comment: > ユーザ側が余計なプログラムを準備する（ユーザに準備させる）手間などを回避できるかもと思ったからです。

この部分については、Go言語が良い解決方法を提供してくれていると思います。Go開発環境とするマシンについては環境整備の必要がありますが、その代わりユーザ側へのインストール作業の負担が大幅に少なくすることが出来ます。開発環境上で設定をすれば様々なOSターゲットごとにバイナリを作ることが出来て、出来上がる実行ファイルは必要なライブラリを全部含む1つのファイルになり、ユーザ環境へはその1つのファイルをインストールするだけですみます。

Comment: @池本雅也 質問者さんは何か勘違いをされていそうです。バイナリはコンパイラによって解釈されるものではありません。動的にリンクされるライブラリの有無を除けば、特定の環境向けにコンパイルされたバイナリは、元のプログラミング言語の言語処理系が存在しなくても動作します。

Comment: すいませんバイナリ配布とソースからコンパイルする場合の両方について考えてました。たしかにバイナリで配布する場合コンパイラと言うか実行環境があるかどうかですね。

Comment: あ、でも質問自体の内容は変更無く今までどうりですのでよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

組み込みOSを別にすれば、いまどきのOSは標準装備でブラウザを持っているので、
javascript(+HTML,CSS)なら汎用性が高そうです。
ElectronとかNWjsなんかはそういう事情を背景に人気があるのだと思います。